# How can I create a rule in Blazegraph with NOT EXISTS constraint?

Tags: rdf, sesame, blazegraph

This question is related to the Blazegraph Java samples. I want to create a rule with a SPARQL `NOT EXISTS` clause. [This Blazegraph rule sample](https://github.com/blazegraph/blazegraph-samples/blob/master/sample-rdf-rules/src/main/java/sample/rdf/rules/SampleRule.java) provides a constraint clause that checks for `IsLiteral()`. I want to implement a rule that provides the following functionality:

```
?a rdf:type xyz:T .
filter(not exits(?a xyz:p ?o)) .
->
?a xyz:q xyz:T
```

I checked for suitable classes in: *com.bigdata.rdf.internal.constraints*
and can't find a `BOp` class that supports `EXIST` (and `MINUS`). I found a `NOT` operator `NotBOp()`.

Here is the constraint that I want to create with a fictitious `ExistsBOp` function:

```
new IConstraint[] { // constraints
    // you can use SPARQL value expression bops in inference by wrapping them with an InferenceBVE
    Constraint.wrap(new InferenceBVE(new NotBOp(new ExistsBOp(var("a"), vocab.getConstant(XYZ.q), vocab.getConstant(XYZ.T))))
}
```

Is there another way to achieve the constraint?